# How to use cygwin cross compiler in Windows to Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cygwin, cross-compiling

I am using Windows OS. I have C project (Eclipse IDE and GCC compiler). I want to generate Linux supported file (*.out file) using Cygwin from Windows. Please let me know how can I do that.

So far I have tried this [link](http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html).

But the procedure given is not clear after installing Cygwin.

Comment: I just read the referenced link.  The instructions were crystal clear,  Exactly where are you in the process and exactly what did you not understand?

Comment: I was trying to download the file "cygwin-gcc-linux.tar.bz2" (file size 62 MB) which is mentioned in the Step2. But given link file size is not more than 75 KB. Please tell me which is the right file that I should download.

Comment: I followed through the posted link.  It is NOT for compiling files on cygwin for linux.  It is some kind of plugin developer for game support.   I do not have a suggested link for the appropriate cross compiler.   sorry